# Virtual Box cannot install Fedora Core 14 Terminate on Call StackTrace

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora, stack

I have virtual box and i want to install Fedora Core 14 with ISO image. After booting, i found error in loading driver and terminate with "Call StackTrace". How can i solve this problem?
If i install it's image to hard drive installation is complete.